# Angular library using forRoot

Tags: angular, angular-library

I am setting up a library that I would like my other projects to use.
I am trying to pass a config file to my module which I have defined like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ImageComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class ImagesModule {
  static forRoot(config: ImagesConfig): ModuleWithProviders<ImagesModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: ImagesModule,
      providers: [{ provide: ImagesConfig, useValue: config }],
    };
  }
}

export class ImagesConfig {
  cloudName: string;
}
```

This looks ok, but now I would like to use the **cloudName** in the actual module, like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ImageComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,

    CloudinaryModule.forRoot(Cloudinary, {
      config.cloudName,
    }),
  ],
})
export class ImagesModule {
  static forRoot(config: ImagesConfig): ModuleWithProviders<ImagesModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: ImagesModule,
      providers: [{ provide: ImagesConfig, useValue: config }],
    };
  }
}

export class ImagesConfig {
  cloudName: string;
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

---

I have created the module as such:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ImageComponent } from './image.component';

import { CloudinaryModule } from '@cloudinary/angular-5.x';
import * as Cloudinary from 'cloudinary-core';

import { ImagesConfig } from './images-config';
import { IMAGES_CONFIG } from './images-config.token';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ImageComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class ImagesModule {
  static forRoot(config: ImagesConfig): ModuleWithProviders<ImagesModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: ImagesModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: IMAGES_CONFIG, useValue: config },
        ...CloudinaryModule.forRoot(Cloudinary, {
          cloud_name: config.cloudName,
        }).providers,
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

**images-config.ts** and **images-config.token.ts** look like this, respectively:

```
export interface ImagesConfig {
  cloudName: string;
}
```

and

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const IMAGES_CONFIG = new InjectionToken('IMAGES_CONFIG');
```

When I try to use in the **public-api.ts**:

```
/*
* Public API Surface of situ-angular-components
*/

export * from './lib/images/images-config';


export * from './lib/images/images.module';
```

It all compiles, but if I try to build my library I get this error:

[image]

---

Unfortunately, the answer @yurzui provided doesn't appear to work.
If I change my module to this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ImageComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CloudinaryModule.forRoot(Cloudinary, { cloud_name: 'demo' }),
  ],
})
export class ImagesModule {}
```

And build my library, it works.
If I do it like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ImageComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class ImagesModule {
  static forRoot(config: ImagesConfig): ModuleWithProviders<ImagesModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: ImagesModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: IMAGES_CONFIG, useValue: config },
        ...CloudinaryModule.forRoot(Cloudinary, {
          cloud_name: config.cloudName,
        }).providers,
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

When I try to build the library, I get an error stating:

> If 'cl-image' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

I am using **cl-image** in the **ImageComponent**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ImageComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CloudinaryModule,
  ],
})
export class ImagesModule {
  static forRoot(config: ImagesConfig): ModuleWithProviders<ImagesModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: ImagesModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: ImagesConfig, useValue: config },
        ...CloudinaryModule.forRoot(Cloudinary, {
          // pass config.cloudName here,
        }).providers,
      ],
    };
  }
}

export class ImagesConfig {
  cloudName: string;
}
```

Comment: that compiles, but when I add it to **public-api.ts** and try to build, I get an error: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Comment: Can you show me screenshot of that error? How did you pass cloudName?

Comment: Looks like this error comes from postcss plugin. It shouldn't be related to how you wrote ts code. At least this is my expectation

Comment: weird, I don't use postcss

Comment: Figured it out :) lol it was in the component, it was looking for a stylesheet that didn't exist

Comment: Angular CLI uses postcss under the hood

Comment: Hmm, it compiles now, but the CloudinaryModule is not imported correctly. I will update my question to show you what I mean

Comment: You forgot to add `CloudinaryModule` to `imports` array. Look at my code

Comment: That seems to work :) I have another issue though, I will post a new question. Perhaps you will know the answer to that too!