# Angular imported library with forRoot throwing error

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have a library that has a static **forRoot** method set up thanks to another question I asked:

[Angular library using forRoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64609920/angular-library-using-forroot)
The problem comes when using this library in another project.
I have imported the module like this:

```
imports: [
  ImagesModule.forRoot({ cloudName: environment.cloudinary.name }),
],
```

This compiles, but if I look in chrome I have this error:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: That's strange. Is it possible to share that library as a github repo so that we can check what's going on?

Comment: Can you show the module that it is exported?

Comment: https://github.com/situlive/situ-angular-components/tree/feature/cloudinary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it; I was following this article:

https://www.usefuldev.com/post/Angular:%20Creating%20configurable%20libraries%20with%20angular%20cli

If you notice it does declares this constant:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { NormalLibConfig } from './normal-lib-config';

export const NORMAL_LIB_CONFIG = new InjectionToken(
  'NORMAL_LIB_CONFIG'
);
```

What I noticed was that even though it imports `NormalLibConfig`, it never actually uses it. So I googled **InjectionToken** and found that it's a generic class. So I updated my implementation to this:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { ImagesConfig } from './images-config';

export const IMAGES_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<ImagesConfig>('IMAGES_CONFIG');
```

And that fixed the issue